# Fastest summarise on a conditional subset

Tags: r, dplyr

```
a = tibble(x = runif(1000,0,10),
           t = rpois(1000,4),
           s = sample(c(0,1),1000, replace = T)
) %>% group_by(t)
```

I want to `summarise` twice `mean(x)` in `a`.

First variable `b1` is `mean(x)` when `s == 0`

Second variable `b2` is `mean(x)` when `s == 1`

Which is the fastest way within a summarise?

Important: I don't want to `group_by(s)`, which is probably the fastest option... the output would be confusing.

Comment: Can [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562656/calculate-the-mean-by-group) be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear to me if you specifically want the summaries with `t` still grouped. This base R approach ignores the grouping.

```
a$b1 <- mean(a$x[a$s == 0])
a$b2 <- mean(a$x[a$s == 1])
```

Or a `dplyr` approach that keeps the grouping of `t`:

```
a %>%
  summarize(b1 = mean(x[s==0]),
            b2 = mean(x[s==1]))
```